# Google sheets query with text

Tags: google-query-language

This is probably a very stupid question but I can't seem to find an answer for it anywhere. I'm trying to use a simple COUNTA query but I also want text to appear so something like this
"Amount = "=COUNTA(B16:B25)

Comment: should work `="Amount: " & COUNTA(A:A)`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for @Stavm

Answer (score 0):

=(your text) & (your formula output)

`="Amount: " & COUNTA(A:A)`

should work.